# How to shift from Windows 8 to Linux Mint Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, cinnamon

I currently have Windows 8 installed in my Dell Inspiron Laptop (I am writing this on Aug 2022). I am facing a lot of issues. I want to switch to Linux Mint Cinnamon completely. I don't want parallel runs with Windows (No dual boot). Please tell me the steps I have to follow, things I have to do before downloading and installing Linux in my system. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1. backup everything to a **different** PC/device 2. make sure your backup is valid and contains all the info 3. before installing Linux wipe everything: `cat /dev/zero > /dev/sda` (this could take up to several hours to complete - not really necessary but I prefer to do that) 4. proceed with the install

Comment: The wiping is superfluous; as Artem says, you can skip it.

Answer (score 0):

As Artem says, make a backup of the files you want to keep somewhere else. That's all steps you need to do. You'll be erasing all the data on the laptop, things you do not backup will be gone.

From here, just follow the Linux mint installation guide https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ :

1. Download the Linux mint installer,
2. Use etcher to error it to a USB memory stick
3. Turn off your laptop, plug in the stick, and tell your PC/laptop to boot from USB
4. Wait until the system has loaded, then double-clock on the "install Linux mint" icon. Just follow the installation program. At some point you're asked whether you want to erase your whole disk and install mint to it - do that!
5. Installation takes a couple of minutes, and then you're good to go